# How do I backup a local SQL Server database in XP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, database-backups

I have developed an ASP.NET 3.5 website on my PC

To deploy the database on the host I use, they require I "restore" it, using a backup of the database.

How do I create this back up of my the database on my PC running XP?

Is there any way to do this in Visual Web Developer? I also downloaded the SQL Server Configuration Manager but I see no option for a backup.

Any help is appreciated!

(Visual Web Developer Express with SQL Server Express 2005)

Thank You.

**EDIT**
**My solution thanks to the answers below:**
Right in Visual Web Developer Express SQL pane I executed the statement -

```
BACKUP DATABASE [C:\Mysite\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF] TO DISK = N'C:\Backup.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'YourDB-Full Database Backup', 
SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10;
```

This created the back up, with some warnings, not really sure what they meant as it mentioned "missing columns" that I am not familiar with. After uploading the database on the host it looked like everything was there, I will be able to test it soon an will update if there is anything I did wrong or missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it through the GUI in management studio or adust the following script and run.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [YourDB] TO  DISK = N'C:\Backup.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'YourDB-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

It is particularly likely that you will need to adjust the file path to somewhere that the service account has permissions to write to (The `Backup` folder in your `MSSQL` directory is a good bet).

Comment: can I run this script outside of the management studio? Having problems connecting the management tool to a "server"...

Comment: @Greg - Yes it's just TSQL so you can run it through any query interface but what does the connection string in your app look like? (with any sensitive information removed)

Answer (score 2):

Get [SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx) (choose Management Tools only) if you don't have it.  It will help you manage your database.  The UI is easy to drive - expand the tree on the left to the database required, and right-click -> Backup Database

Comment: ok, I don't think I got the management tool when i downloaded...thanks

Comment: when I start it up there is no server to connect to? (I have vS web developer up and running with the database connected - ASP.NET Development Server is running)

Comment: @Greg - What if you try `.\SQLEXPRESS` as the servername and Windows Authentication? Also is your database a user instance?

Comment: @Martin: No good using ".\SQLEXPRESS". I don't know if my database is a user instance, how would I find that out. (sorry for delay)